# mvc4 how to convert image to byte array in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have this form in view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddOneImage", "ApartmentImages", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <p>
        @Html.TextBox("image", "", new { placeholder = "Uploadt New Image", type = "file"})
        <input type="submit" value="Add" />
    </p>
}
```

It works but it sends the name of the image to the controller.

I need to send the **byte array** or the **base64** of that image

#### What have I tried

I tried adding this tag

```
src="data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(image)
```

to the form, but still nothing work

Comment: First of all, if you are trying to upload a file to the server, you need to add this HTML attribute to the form: ``enctype = "multipart/form-data"``

Comment: Secondly, are you trying to put an image in a textbox on purpose or are you just trying things to get it to work?

Comment: @acfrancis i added the `multipart/form-data` and still not working, i cant use a model here in this view because i already have a model and i want to just allow the user to add images. please help

Comment: For some reason MVC4 doesn't include a method for input type file so I just use the html tag instead: ``<input type="file" name="image" />``

Comment: You will also need some code in the controller action that receives the form post to convert the uploaded image to a byte array or base64 string. Do you want a code sample?